# How to chagne authorization field in nginx basic auth?

Tags: authentication, nginx

I have nginx basic auth on my VueJS application.  MY vuejs application has laravel api that use jwt and authorization field for authentication.
but there is some complication that I should use nginx basic auth . but nginx use `authorization` field in header for handle. I use it to. How I can change nginx basic auth header field.

I use this code as nginx basic auth.

```
     auth_basic "Username and Password are required";
     auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

Comment: Why you want to change it? What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: we have an application that use authorization header for this, but there are two scope, and user authenticated with same gateway. we want users that belog to scope 1 don't access to scope 2, with sample user and password

Comment: Not sure I got it. You mean authenticated user must be able to access location1, but not be able to access location2?

Comment: I have a same problem. In my staging server. I would like to configure nginx basic auth. Unfortunately, my oAuth server is using authorization header too.